# How to ensure that one instruction is finished before a second instruction is started on a pipelined CPU?

Tags: assembly, cpu, cpu-architecture, pipelining

Supposing there are two sequential instructions, like this:

```
instruction A
instruction B
```

Because of CPU pipelining, B will start before A finishes.

Does there exist a mechanism to ensure B starts after A finishes?

**UPDATE:**
I'm sorry about that I have not described the problem accurately. I mean, this two instructions has application-level ordering dependency but no hazard. For example, in a transaction system, the first instruction is flushing logs to persistent storage and the second instruction is noticing clients about transaction commit. So we can't execute the second instruction until the first finish. How to provide this execution order?

Comment: You mean a pipeline stall? Also what does this have to do with C (or Assembly)?

Comment: There are a number of barriers that can be implemented in a variety of instruction set architectures, this question isn't well written enough to know which to address.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? It would be quite dumb for CPU designers to add instructions to slow things down for no reason whatsoever. There are instructions on various CPUs, but they are for solving specific ordering problems (like memory, traps, etc.), I've not seen specific instructions to stall the pipeline just for the sake of it though.

Comment: CPUs have a lot of logic built into them to avoid starting B if it depends on A.  If you have a specific case where (somehow) B depends on A, but B is running before A is complete, provide details.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves so many downvotes. Though pipelining alone doesn't mean that "B starts before A finishes" (because the CPU needs more than a single execution unit to be super-scalar and eventually OoO), serialising instructions is an important aspect of programming.

Comment: For the update part, the scenario you are asking will not become two separate instructions, instead many instructions. I don't think your problems applies to the CPU pipeline, rather it seems like a barrier problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because of CPU pipelining, B will start before A finishes.

So? Why is this a problem?

In a basic [pipelined architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining), instruction A will start executing on the first cycle, and then instruction B will start executing on the next cycle.

Taking the [basic 5-stage RISC pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline) as an example, it would look like this:

```
Clock Cycle   |    1    |    2     |     3     |      4      |      5      |      6      |
--------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instruction A |  Fetch  |  Decode  |  Execute  | Mem. Access |  Writeback  |
Instruction B |         |  Fetch   |  Decode   |   Execute   | Mem. Access |  Writeback  |
```

The processor would begin fetching instruction A on the first clock cycle. On the second clock cycle, it would begin decoding instruction A, while it was *simultaneously* fetching instruction B. And so on, down the pipeline.

The reason this works so well is that the instruction *fetching* unit is a completely separate piece of hardware from the instruction *decoding* unit (even though both may be implemented on the same slab of silicon), so it makes sense to keep each of these units occupied simultaneously. This is one mechanism for achieving [instruction-level parallelism (ILP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism).

Ultimately, you can see that Instruction A will complete on cycle 5, while instruction B won't complete until cycle 6. Still, that's way better than instruction A completing on cycle 5 and instruction B not being able to *start* until cycle 6, deferring its completion until cycle 11.

Logic internal to the processor handles instructional dependencies, so if instruction B somehow relies on the result of instruction A, the processor's decoder will be able to detect that and will *stall* the execution of instruction B until its data is available (i.e., until instruction A gets far enough along in the pipeline that its results are ready). This is all handled seamlessly for you, but it does introduce performance costs ([pipeline bubbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_(computing))), so you want to avoid it whenever possible. That means writing your code so that instructions with dependencies are spread out as far as possible from each other, with independent instructions interspersed in between.

> Does there exist a mechanism to ensure B starts after A finishes?

Yes, such mechanisms generally exist, but you don't usually want to *use* them because they slow execution down by defeating the entire advantage of a pipeline.

These mechanisms are referred to as *serializing* instructions (or sometimes "barriers") because they erect a barrier that causes execution to be serialized at a particular point.

For example, on the x86 architecture, the `CPUID` instruction is a serializing instruction (actually, [one of several](http://www.sandpile.org/x86/coherent.htm)). So you could do:

```
Instruction A
CPUID
Instruction B
```

and this would ensure that instruction B will not start until *after* instruction A finishes executing.

From the Intel architecture manuals:

> `CPUID` can be executed at any privilege level to serialize instruction execution. Serializing instruction execution guarantees that any modifications to flags, registers, and memory for previous instructions are completed before the next instruction is fetched and executed.
>
> See also: "Serializing Instructions" in Chapter 7 of the [IA-32 Intel Architecture Software Developer's Manual, Volume 3](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/325384-sdm-vol-3abcd.pdf) AP-485, Intel Processor Identification and the CPUID Instruction.

Technically, this doesn't guarantee that Instruction B won't start down the pipeline. The processor might, for example, decode and fetch instruction B before it finishes executing instruction A. However, from the *programmer's* perspective (i.e., observable behavior), it will be as if instruction B is only started after instruction A has finished.

Comment: Truly grateful for your help.

Comment: off-topic, but have you seen [Reverse the \[memory-barriers\] \[memory-order\] synonym situation so questions about C++ std::memory\_order can be tagged memory-order, not barriers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419899) on meta?  Seems like there's a consensus, just waiting on a moderator to do the tag swapping.  And you're a mod I know who has some experience in CPU-architecture stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of serialization, for instructions only, you need serializing / scoreboarding instructions, which prevent younger ones from entering the OOO machine before the previous one commits. `CPUID` does that but is very heavy. Some other instructions may do that as well (see below).

Then, there are memory oriented mechanisms to ensure the load or store buffers are drained, mostly for memory ordering purporses. `LFENCE` and `SFENCE` guarantee that respectively, while `MFENCE` does both. It's important to note that this is somewhat orthogonal to the instruction serialization, and Intel's developers manual for example states:

> The MFENCE instruction is ordered with respect to all load and store
>   instructions, other MFENCE instructions, any LFENCE and SFENCE
>   instructions, and any serializing instructions (such as the CPUID
>   instruction). **MFENCE does not serialize the instruction stream**

There could be combinations, for example I think a locked operation (e.g. locked inc) guarantees for instructions and memory serialization (the first due to memory ordering, the latter due to atomicity). See also chapter 8 in vol 3A here - https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf

Finally, what you need is also a way to ensure the data is written to memory (or persistent storage in some cases. Having a store buffer drain still means that the data can reside in a local cache. On normal WB memory this is enough, as any other observer would have to snoop it out and get the update, but in some cases you want to ensure the data isn't lost due to some crash. For that you can use a CLFLUSH/CLFLUSHOPT, or PCOMMIT ([deprecated on some systems](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2016/09/12/deprecate-pcommit-instruction)) / CLWB

Again - all the above have different meaning, depending on what you need.

Comment: Be careful with `PAUSE`. First of all, it has no meaning on CPUs prior to the Pentium 4, which are nevertheless pipelined. Second, it's *designed* as a hint to the processor that a code sequence is a spin-wait loop (not that this is really ever good programming practice), and therefore avoid the memory order violation. It is not really a serialization instruction. A better way to think of it is as *yielding* the processor, and it only yields to other threads so it only makes in the context of a single HyperThreaded (SMT) CPU. "Heavy" comes with the territory of serialization.

Comment: @CodyGray, I was trying to show that instruction ordering is not the same as memory ordering. Also - pause doesn't only yield to the other thread, otherwise there was no sense in using in in single thread mode (you would still rush to perform as many spin loop iterations as your processor can hold). But I agree pause has inconsistent meaning (although, really, who runs pre-P4?), and isn't a good idea here. Removed it.

Comment: You use `PAUSE` in single-thread mode because of HyperThreading. There is otherwise no point, that's why it didn't exist prior to P4. As for who runs anything before P4, I don't know. I guess no one in the "real world", but we still get a lot of questions here about 16-bit DOS programming.